# I use action to send a request and return the result to reducer, but store can't receive the result

Tags: redux

when componentDidMount i dispatch an action to send a request, this is the action code below. receiveUserInfo just return data to reducer

```js
export function requestUserInfo() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getUserInfo())
    return axios.post('/user/getScores', qs.stringify({
        token: token,
        uid: uid
      }))
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.status !== 200) {
          message.error(res.data.message)
          return state
        }
        // return the data from server
        return { ...res.data.attachment}
      })
      .then(data => {
        // receiveUserInfo just return action and data
        dispatch(receiveUserInfo(data))
      })
  }
}
```

this is the reducer code.

```js
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
const uid = localStorage.getItem('uid')

export const requestUserInfo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'HEADER_GET_USERINFO':
    case 'HEADER_RECEIVE_USERINFO':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.data)
      break
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```js
function receiveUserInfo(data) {
  return {
    type: 'HEADER_RECEIVE_USERINFO',
    data
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem, cna you add receiveUserInfo code too

Comment: well,it is just a simple function

Comment: Any errors in console

Comment: there is no error

Comment: Then the problem could be `dispatch(getUserInfo())` statement, remove that and see the result

Comment: it delete it and subscribe store, there is no influence

Comment: No need to use `break` if you use the `return` statement. Also, you have to spread your data: `Object.assign({}, state, ...action.data)`. Question: are you using `redux-thunk` and/or `redux-promise`?

Comment: thx, i use redux-chunk package